# R SVM return NA for predictions with missing data

Tags: r, svm

I am attempting to make predictions using a trained SVM from package e1071 but my data contains some missing values (NA).

I would like the returned predictions to be NA when that instance has any missing values. I tried to use na.action = na.pass as below but it gives me an error "Error in names(ret2) <- rowns : 'names' attribute [150] must be the same length as the vector [149]".

If I use na.omit then I can get predictions without instances with missing data.
How can I get predictions including NAs?

```
library(e1071)
model <- svm(Species ~ ., data = iris)
print(length(predict(model, iris)))
tmp <- iris
tmp[1, "Sepal.Length"] <- NA
print(length(predict(model, tmp, na.action = na.pass)))
```

Comment: You could just assign all the valid cases back to a prediction variable in the `tmp` set - `tmp[complete.cases(tmp), "predict"] <- predict(model, newdata=tmp[complete.cases(tmp),])` or equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, this is great.  Given that I have to work with SVMs and want NA rather than imputation this is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

if you are familiar with the [caret package](http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html), where you can use 233 different types of models to fit (Including SVM from package e1071), in the section called ["models clustered by tag similarity"](http://topepo.github.io/caret/models-clustered-by-tag-similarity.html) there you can find a csv with the data they used to group the algorithms.

There is a column there called *Handle Missing Predictor Data*, which tells you which algorithms can do what you want. Unfortunately SVM is not included there, but these algorithms are:

- Boosted Classification Trees (ada)
- Bagged AdaBoost (AdaBag)
- AdaBoost.M1 (AdaBoost.M1)
- C5.0 (C5.0)
- Cost-Sensitive C5.0 (C5.0Cost)
- Single C5.0 Ruleset (C5.0Rules)
- Single C5.0 Tree (C5.0Tree)
- CART (rpart)
- CART (rpart1SE)
- CART (rpart2)
- Cost-Sensitive CART (rpartCost)
- CART or Ordinal Responses (rpartScore)

If you still insist on using SVM, you could use the knnImpute option in the [preProccess function](http://topepo.github.io/caret/pre-processing.html#imputation) from the same package, that should allow you to predict for all your observations.

Answer (score 1):

You could just assign all the valid cases back to a prediction variable in the `tmp` set:

```
tmp[complete.cases(tmp), "predict"] <- predict(model, newdata=tmp[complete.cases(tmp),]) 
tmp

#    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species    predict
#1             NA         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa       <NA>
#2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa     setosa
#3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa     setosa
# ...
```