# How to return NAs for predictions where some predictors have missing values

Tags: r, predict

This is very similar with the following question: [R SVM return NA for predictions with missing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42334759/r-svm-return-na-for-predictions-with-missing-data)

However, the response suggested there does not work (at least for me). Therefore I would like to be more general and try a different approach (or adjust the one proposed there). I can predict using my svm model on the complete.cases() of my data frame. However, it is very important for me to have NA values for all rows with missing data.

My theoretical approach should be the following: predict on complete.cases() of my data frame. Find the index of complete cases. Somehow cbind the column with predictions back to my data.frame(), while adding NA values for all values whose indices are different from those of complete cases. In the essence I should create a column in a data frame by combining two vectors: one of predictions, the other of NA values (based on known indices). However, I am stupid enough not to be able to write the few lines of code for doing that.

Comment: Maybe using ifelse to write in a new column a predicted value or NA, depending on the existence of missing values in a row could also be an approach. But I still am not able to write the code.

Comment: Hard to do without data, but: if `x` is your data (potentially with missingness), then `x$pred <- NA; x$pred[complete.cases(x)] <- predict(mdl, newdata=x[complete.cases(x),])`. Disregard, this is exactly what thelatemail suggested. Since it *"does not work"* and that is the idiomatic way to do it, you need to provide a reproducible question. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(x=...,y=...)`), and expected output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I've just discovered that the solution in the question mentioned in the introduction works, provided that I select only the column with the prediction. At least under "mlr" R package, the result of predict applied to a svm model is a list, and in order for the solution to work, I have to use for assignement the $data$response component of that list.

Comment: Several methods of `predict` return a `list`, sometimes with `$y`, sometimes something else. Glad to hear that was "all" it was.